# Is there a way of creating a new arithmetic function in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I was wondering if there is a way of adding my own arithmetic function to a Google Sheet. I want it to work like this:

When I type into a cell `=myFunc(B2, B3)` (for example) it will fill in the cell with the return value of `myFunc`. One way I suppose I could do this is to check if I have typed that combination anywhere in the spreadsheet and then replace it with the desired output using Google Apps Script, but this seems inefficient.

Is there another way I could accomplish this, such as with an addon?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's called a custom function. Search the official documentation. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for free resources.

Comment: @TheMaster thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! Could you please post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're  looking for [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). Any valid JavaScript  function in Tools > script editor(a bound script file) can be called in any cell of that spreadsheet.